# export database using php code in .sql Extension?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to export the database with .sql Extension using PHP code?

## Example

database name: `demodb`
DB contains two tables

table one: `user`

table two: `registration`

Comment: All you have to do is build `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements with your PHP code and put into your SQL file.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes** Its possible .

```
 <?php
        //ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
        $mysqlDatabaseName ='xxxxxx';
        $mysqlUserName ='xxxxxxx';
        $mysqlPassword ='myPassword';
        $mysqlHostName ='xxxxxxxx.net';
        $mysqlExportPath ='chooseFilenameForBackup.sql';

        //DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
        //Export the database and output the status to the page
        $command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
        exec($command);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use **mysqldump** command for mySql db:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysql_username -h mysql_host -p mysql_password database_name> /path_to_export_location/file_name.sql";
exec($command, NULL, NULL);
```

make a look at documentation in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)