# export sql in php UTF-8

Tags: php, sql, database, utf-8, export

I want to export all of tables of my db in sql file using php with encoding UTF-8
whats the best way! whats the code!
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your query after this:

```
$db = new MySQLi("host", "username", "password", "db");

if(!$db)
{
    die("your_error_msg" . mysqli_error($db));
}

$db->set_charset("utf8");'
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    //ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
    $mysqlDatabaseName ='xxxxxx';
    $mysqlUserName ='xxxxxxx';
    $mysqlPassword ='myPassword';
    $mysqlHostName ='xxxxxxxx.net';
    $mysqlExportPath ='chooseFilenameForBackup.sql';

    //DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    //Export the database and output the status to the page
    $command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' --default-character-set=utf8 ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
    exec($command);
 ?>
```

From: [export database using php code in .sql Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424514/export-database-using-php-code-in-sql-extension), but I added the `--default-character-set=utf8` part

Comment: i know that , my problem is exporting... whats the code for export a db as .sql file

Comment: Ah. I read it quickly so I misunderstood. Hehe. check my edit